# Create partition on new raid1 hardware

Tags: server, partitioning, raid, disk, fdisk

In future, I'll need to add more 2 disks over RAID1 on my ubuntu server.

I already has a RAID1, but I have more 2 slots in my server and I'll put there more 2 disks to create another RAID1.

I never did it, the only thing I did is simply add normal disks (not in RAID).

My concern is will I need to do something different from the traditional?

Something like, first activate the RAID (as I did when I was installing the ubuntu in the currently RAID1).

Or this will be automatic and I only will need to create the partitions and format them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer is not a mind reader so it can't automagically know you want to create a new raid array when you plug in two new disks.  You will have to create the new array the same as you had to for the first one.